# Ember is there alternative way for binding elements attributes

Tags: ember.js, html-parsing, jsoup, handlebars.js

I have a dynamically created Ember's views which are connected from some sub-parts stored in the DB. I'm also using a Jsoup for modifying the template to include some other non-Ember parts. Unfortunately when my stored ember part contains attribute binding in common way:

```
<li {{bindAttr class="isCompleted:completed isEditing:editing"}}>
```

The Jsoup tries to "fix" them by adding empty quotes like, which is of course expected behavior:

```
<li {{bindattr="" class="isCompleted:completed isEditing:editing" }}="">
```

Is there any way for binding the attributes ie. by wrapping it within some valid HTML
ie. like `data-ember='{{bindAttr "something"}}'` or at least a way for preventing Jsoup from these changes?

Comment: Can you explain what jsoup does in this mix? I know it as server side API to parse and manipulate HTML. How does this relate to a Handlebars Template on the client?

Comment: That's simple, I'm creating simple tool to manage the email's template. user can login to the backend and create new set of fields just with predefined elements (that's not an Ember part still) next I'm saving it and convert to the Ember's template, which is used while creating new mail, I'm using Jsoup for traversing the incoming HTML and so I can add non-Ember dynamic parts to the final template. Note that these additional parts can't be switched to Ember's logic

Comment: @mavilein in shorter form - Jsoup creates the Ember's view dynamically in this mix :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is (as you surely already know) that **Jsoup** tries to parse your `HTML` markup with the included **handlebars** expressions, and by doing so it check's for valid `HTML`, so in the case of `bindAttr` this is interpreted as a attribute for your `<li>` tag, and because a valid attribute is something like `class="foo"` Jsoup converts it to `bindAttr=""`.

Lamentably there is no built-in way of telling Jsoup to ignore tags with no values. I guess you should try another tool that fit's your needs.

Hope it helps.